# Media queries in my css do not work

Tags: html, css, debugging, responsive-design, media-queries

I have issues with my media queries. It seems like they do not work in either browser. I tried in Opera, Chrome, Firefox. This is the page http://amatalents.com/about-us.html and those are media-queries for main div section

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 150) and (max-width: 400) {
       .windows div {
           width: 100%;
           display: table-column;
         }
       .windows div a {
           font-size: 10px;
           color: green;
         }
       .windows {
           background-color: red;
         }
       }
```

I also validated the css file and first time it did fine and only mentioned the css parser error reffering to media queries part of the file, but the second time it referred to media queries only without mentioning parser error. 
   I am lost...
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing px.
     @media screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 400px)

Comment: I had a feeling it was something stupid...)))Thanks a lot!Now everything is flying!